# I have designed a page in flutter where the landscape and portrait layouts differ. Can't get layout to change when I rotate device

Tags: flutter, layout

The code snippet below is how I generate my page. I detect the screenWidth and screenHeight and then use these values to detect if the page should be displayed in portrait or landscape.

The two factions return data type of Scaffold and the appropriate layout is rendered depending on screen orientation.

```
class UserInstructions extends StatefulWidget {
    const UserInstructions({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    _UserInstructionsState createState() => _UserInstructionsState();
}//***************** class UserInstructions ends **************************

class _UserInstructionsState  extends State<UserInstructions> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      double screenWidth = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) ;
      double screenHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
      if (screenWidth < screenHeight) { // we are in portrait mode
          return portraitLayout();
      }
      else {//( screenWidth > screenHeight) we are in landscape mode
          return landscapeLayout();
      }//else( screenWidth > screenHeight) we are in landscape mode
  }//********************** Widget build ends *****************************
}//*************** class _UserInstructionsState ends **********************
I have created 2 functions:-

Scaffold portraitLayout() {
    return Scaffold (
        body: Centre(
.
.
.
}//*********** function  portraitLayout ends************


Scaffold landscapeLayout() {
    return Scaffold (
        body: Centre(
.
.
.
}//**************** function  landscapeLayout ends *******************

these functions provide the differing screen layouts for the two orientations.

When I rotate the simulator screen between orientations I would like the new orientation layout to take effect.  Only way I can achieve this at the moment is by using hot reload.  I have tried using
double screenWidth = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)  inside my functions but the compiler complains giving me a context error 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.
I’m at a loss any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Material Widget called layout builder that can help you achieve this very efficiently.
The sample code is as follows.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('LayoutBuilder Example')),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation ==
                                    Orientation.portrait) {
            return _buildNormalContainer();
          } else {
            return _buildWideContainers();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNormalContainer() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWideContainers() {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can find the documentation here. [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)